# Change the order on element

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, addsubview, superview

I'm now doing an application, where i need to put some elements in the top of the views sometimes.

For example, how could i do to make the entire CGRect red and not the green visible here :

[image: example]

Could i call addSubview method more than one time, and it won't be sad in memory management ?

Because i've tried a lot of things, like :

```
[myUIImageView removeFromSuperview];
[muUIVew addsubview:myUIImageView];
```

or :

```
[myUIImageView didMoveToSuperview];
```

But it gaves me an error...
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should call `addSubview` once. There are methods to manage subview position.

This is two methods you can use:

```
[muUIVew sendSubviewToBack: myUIImageView];

[muUIVew bringSubviewToFront: myUIImageView];
```

Should be pretty clear what they do.

Comment: Thanks guy, i've tried this, and it doesn't looks like working but the problem must be in another part of my code, because with another image it looks like working o_O